# EF auto generates foreign key field while making database transaction which is not exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm working on one project where we use entity framework for database transaction.
While making a database transaction, if there's any reference key in particular table, then it autogenerates new field for that referenced entity which doesn't even exist.

For Example:

> I've one table called **Stations** which has a **reference of
>   StationTypes**(one-to-one).
>
> Now whenever we try to create/update any record in Stations table, it
>   by defaylt inject one field called "StationType_Id" into particular
>   query called "StationType_Id" - which is not even exist and end up in
>   throwing bellow error.

```
Invalid column name 'StationTypes_Id'.
```

Sample DB entity generated by EF

```
public partial class Stations
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Stations()
    {
        this.OrganizationStations = new HashSet<OrganizationStations>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int StationTypeId { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationStations> OrganizationStations { get; set; }
    public virtual StationTypes StationTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This indicates improper entity model mapping. And should affect all database table operations, including read (not only add/update). You need to provide the relevant entity classes and fluent configuration (if any) in order to get concrete answer what is wrong.

Comment: @IvanStoev that's correct, its affecting all DB operations including read, so how can I verify that which mapping is incorrect?

Comment: @IvanStoev have added sample class of Stations

Comment: "StationTypes_Id" is the conventional name for a FK associated with `public virtual StationTypes StationTypes { get; set; }` navigation property. Do you have a FK column in the associated db table? Mapping one-to-one in EF6 has some issues, can you also post the `StationTypes` class? Also you may need to look at the relationship properties in the EDMX designer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it would actually be a Many-to-1 relationship. A Station has 1 station type, but many stations may have that same station type.

In this case, it would be expected that a Station record would have a StationTypeId column. You will likely not want to expose a StationTypeId property in your Station entity so to map this in EF 6:

using modelBuilder

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Station>
   .HasRequired(x => x.StationType)
   .WithMany()
   .Map(x => x.MapKey("StationTypeId"));
```

A 1-to-1 relationship would have the StationType table sharing a StationId PK with the Station table. In this case a Station would have a reference to a StationType, and a StationType would have a reference to a Station. EF would then link these together by PK:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Station>
   .HasRequired(x => x.StationType)
   .WithRequired(x => x.Station);
```

This can be set up with a FK to FK relationship, but one FK must be null-able.

Comment: you're right it should be many to one, but as per the current design its one-to-one relationship,
the solution you suggested that might work but we've 100s of tables in our edmx which has this type of references, so do I need to write this line for all those tables ? isn't there something Global which I can mention at entity framework level ?

Comment: If the classes were generated by the EDMX then I believe EF would have declared the FK fields in the entities and associated them. Does your Station entity class contain a field called StationTypeId? If so, `.Map()` would be replaced with `.HasForeignKey("StationTypeId")` If the Station entity has the FK but not mapping automatically then the issue would likely be that it's not set as a FK to StationType in the DB. If you want a 1 to 1, then StationType would need StationId as PK+FK back to Station to work out of the box. Otherwise Station needs a nullable StationTypeId and conf. manually.

Comment: Yes, station class has that field "StationTypeId", have updated class in my question accordingly, but my concern is why do I need to update explicitly mention that my entity has this reference field, it was not the case for any of my previous project, and same thing I would need to mention for all those 100s tables, isn't there any alternate way to do this globally ?

Comment: If the EDMX had put StationTypeId on Station but hadn't mapped the HasForeignKey then I would suspect that your Database schema does not have the FK set up. I'm not that familiar with the use of EDMXs as that was years ago, but if you're generating the EDMX from an existing schema the schema may be missing the FK associations. If you're building the schema with the EDMX you need to specify the FK relationships in the EDMX. If the EDMX knows about the FKs it should wire the entities up correctly. FKs are also needed for performance and data integrity.